# prevent back button on to previous page - angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, browser

From within my controller, I am attempting to disable or prevent back button from within an angularjs controller after making a get request and navigating to a page. The disabling of the back button or prevent going back to the previous page has not happened. This is my snippet

```
$scope.goToDashboardAfterLogin=   function () {
                    $http({
                        method: 'GET',
                        url: '/page',
                    else if (response.status == 200) {


                            $(window).on("keypress", function (e){
                                if(e.keycode == "backspace") 
                                     e.preventDefault();
                            })

                            $(location).attr('href', '/page2');
                        }
                    }, function errorCallback(response) {
                        alert(JSON.stringify(response));
                    });
                };
```

how can I achieve prevent going back to the previous page from the browser from tha above attempt

Comment: You want to handle backspace only or the browser back button also ?

Comment: I think you missed a bit of your function when you pasted it in. Also, what router are you using? ngRoute or ui-router?

Answer (score -1):

Did you try 'return false'?

```
$(window).on("keypress", function (e){
                            if(e.keycode == "backspace") 
                                 return false;
                        });
```

e.preventDefault() will prevent the default event from occuring, e.stopPropagation() will prevent the event from bubbling up and return false will do both.

Comment: with the above I can still go back to the previous page